# function should add user to a list in other friend's node in Firebase but instead it returns nil

Tags: ios, swift, function, firebase

I have a modal view (made in storyboard) named `CloseFriendsController`  with a button that should add the current user to a list in Firebase titled `closeFriends` and then dismiss the modal view. I created the function in the `CloseFriendsController` and called it when the button is tapped:

```
var buttonFunc: (() -> (Void))!

@IBAction func addToCloseFriends(_ sender: UIButton) {
    buttonFunc()
    self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    print("Added to Close Friends!")
}

func setFunction(_ function: @escaping () -> Void) {
    self.buttonFunc = function
}
```

This is the CloseFriendsController (the "Yeah I'm down!" button is linked to the `addToCloseFriends` function):

[image: Screenshot from Storyboard]

The function is set in the `cellForItemAt indexPath` of the cell where the current user is to be displayed:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let closeFriends = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)

    let closeFriendsController = CloseFriendsController()
    closeFriendsController.setFunction {
        let id = CloseFriendsSystem.system.friendList[indexPath.row].uid
        CloseFriendsSystem.system.addCurrentUserToFriendsCloseFriendsLists(id)
        print("currentUser added to Friends' Close Friends list!!")

    }

    return closeFriends
}
```

The `print("Added to Close Friends!")` statement prints when `buttonFunc()` is commented out, but the `buttonFunc()` line is causing the app to crash with the warning:

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I've created a function, called it and set it in the same way multiple times before. However, in those instances, the button that called the function was inside the cell where the `cellForItemAt indexPath` was referencing. Because of this, I'm thinking I need to find a different way to call the indexPath? But I don't know how I'd go about this.

I tried creating a delegate with a function that would cause the `buttonFunc` function to be created in the same controller where it's set. However, the function in the other controller was never called.

I'm really stuck here, so any help would be amazing!!

Comment: I am constructing your answer now. Are you presenting CloseFriendsController with segue or self.present() method?

Comment: I'm using this this CustomAlertViewTransitioner.swift: https://github.com/mattneub/custom-alert-view-iOS7/blob/master/CustomAlertViewDemo/CustomAlertViewTransitioner.swift

Comment: Also, would you mind adding screenshot of your CollectionView?

Comment: I added a screenshot from the storyboard to the original post (thanks in advance for your help!)

Comment: Did you try the solution I posted?

Comment: Yeah, I'm just having trouble with the `self.present` line where you said to change it based on how I'm presenting. The `didSelectItemAt` would be going in a cell that's in a controller that is presented by the mainTabBarController. How would I present that?

Comment: Could you update your question with code that you are using to present `CloseFriendsController`?

Comment: So, the CloseFriendsController is being presented with the CustomAlertViewTransitioner I posted in the above comment (it's at this link: https://github.com/mattneub/custom-alert-view-iOS7/blob/master/CustomAlertViewDemo/CustomAlertViewTransitioner.swift). However, the `didSelectItemAt` is going in a cell that's in a separate controller (not the CloseFriendsController). I don't know if that changes the approach (you're obviously more well versed in iOS programming than me). It's recommending to go into chat to discuss this, but I only have 15 reputation (and you need 20 to chat).

Comment: @Bhaumik I found out the problem was in my approach to trying to put the data into my firebase database. I've posted a new question if you want to see if you can figure it out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54909910/i-want-to-take-the-currentusers-userid-and-add-it-as-a-child-to-all-their-frien (thanks again for all your help!!)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

You need to change CollectionView delegate and datasource code as below:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
   let closeFriends = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)
   return closeFriends
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   // initialize closeFriendsController
   let closeFriendsController = CloseFriendsController() // change this line as you need
   closeFriendsController.id = CloseFriendsSystem.system.friendList[indexPath.row].uid
   // present closeFriendsController
   self.present(closeFriendsController, animated: true, completion: nil) // change this line if you are presenting differently
}
```

In your CloseFriendsController:

Remove <strike>var buttonFunc: (() -> (Void))!</strike>

```
var id: String!

@IBAction func addToCloseFriends(_ sender: UIButton) {
   guard let id = self.id else { return }
   CloseFriendsSystem.system.addCurrentUserToFriendsCloseFriendsLists(id)
   self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
   print("Added to Close Friends!")
}
```

Also, Remove 
<strike>func setFunction(_ function: @escaping () -> Void) {</strike>

self.buttonFunc = function

}