# I want to take the currentUser's userId and add it as a child to all their friend's data- in Firebase with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my Firebase database, the parent data is all the users' `userId`s. They each have a `child("friends")` which contains a list of all their friends' `userId`s.

I want to get each `currentUser`'s friends' `userId`s and add the `currentUser`'s `userId` to each of their friends' `child("closeFriends")` node

This is how my data structure looks:

```
users
    10XeC8j6OCcFTKj8Dm7lR7dVnkf1
        email: "Dummy19@gmail.com"
        fcmToken: "cBW9XhpYqio:APA91bF6K5YgRj0PgyDCoApNpIWGO4icwFg..."
        friends
            ekFjYJU8OWTbYnQXVzhcxVE0wBP2: true
        profileImageUrl: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/jar..."
        username: "Dummy19"
    ePt3MSOuk6ZYDfekewmPlG4LgcU2
        email: "Dummy20@gmail.com"
        fcmToken: "cBW9XhpYqio:APA91bF6K5YgRj0PgyDCoApNpIWGO4icwFg..."
        friends
            ekFjYJU8OWTbYnQXVzhcxVE0wBP2: true
            u43NtDYmqeTxafmLYjxxt60ngUo1: true
        profileImageUrl: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/jar..."
        username: "Dummy20"
    ekFjYJU8OWTbYnQXVzhcxVE0wBP2
        email: "Dummy18@gmail.com"
        fcmToken: "cF-b_Fd8Ufc:APA91bG9bir1o_jdJdfB35l9g9HlNNTNHPM..."
        friends
            10XeC8j6OCcFTKj8Dm7lR7dVnkf1: true
            ePt3MSOuk6ZYDfekewmPlG4LgcU2: true
        profileImageUrl: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/jar..."
        username: "Dummy18"
    u43NtDYmqeTxafmLYjxxt60ngUo1
        email: "Dummy21@gmail.com"
        fcmToken: "cBW9XhpYqio:APA91bF6K5YgRj0PgyDCoApNpIWGO4icwFg..."
        friends
            ePt3MSOuk6ZYDfekewmPlG4LgcU2: true
        profileImageUrl: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/jar..."
        username: "Dummy21"
```

And I want 'closeFriends' to be a node with `userId`s just like `friends` is already.

These are my reference variables and functions:

```
let userReference = Database.database().reference().child("users")

var currentUserReference: DatabaseReference {
    let id = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    return userReference.child("\(id)")
}

var currentUserFriendsReference: DatabaseReference {
    return currentUserReference.child("friends")
}

var currentUserCloseFriendsReference: DatabaseReference {
    return currentUserReference.child("closeFriends")
}

var currentUserId: String {
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    return uid
}

func getCurrentUser(_ completion: @escaping (User) -> Void) {
    currentUserReference.observeSingleEvent(of: DataEventType.value) { (snapshot) in
        let email: String = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "email").value as! String
        let uid = snapshot.key

        let username = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "username").value as! String

        let profileImageUrl = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "profileImageUrl").value as! String

        completion(User(uid: uid, userUsername: username, userProfileImageUrl: profileImageUrl, userEmail: email))
    }
}

func getUser(_ userId: String, completion: @escaping (User) -> Void) {
    userReference.child(userId).observeSingleEvent(of: DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let email = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "email").value as! String
        let uid = snapshot.key

        // Did the same thing here as in the above function
        let username = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "username").value as! String

        let profileImageUrl = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "profileImageUrl").value as! String

        completion(User(uid: uid, userUsername: username, userProfileImageUrl: profileImageUrl, userEmail: email))
    })
}

var closeFriendList = [User]()
```

I tried this `for` loop, but it did nothing:

```
func addCurrentUserToCloseFriendsLists(_ userId: String){
    for friend in friendList{
        let id = friend.uid
        self.getUser(id) { (user) in
            self.closeFriendList.append(user)
            self.userReference.child(userId).child("closeFriends").child(self.currentUserId).setValue(true)
        }
    }
```

For reference, `friendList` is the list of friends created in another file (my "FriendSystem").

I'm sure there's another way to fetch all the user's friends and then run a loop to add the `currentUser` to all those friends' `child("closeFriends")`, I just haven't been able to figure it out.

Super stuck on this, hope you can help! Thanks!

Comment: Can you please include a snippet of your Firebase structure to clarify the question? Include that as text please, no images.

Comment: @Jay I added the contents of my Firebase database. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to get each currentUser's friends' userIds and add the
>   currentUser's userId to each of their friends' child("closeFriends")
>   node

Let start with a simple users structure similar to yours:

```
users
   uid_0
      name: "Larry"
      friends:
         uid_1: true
         uid_2: true
   uid_1
       name: "Moe"
   uid_2
       name: "Curly"
```

The idea is to go through this users (the current user) friends list and add this users uid to the other users friends list. In this example, I am just creating a 'friends' node for each user but you can make it 'closeFriends' or whatever name you want.

Here's the code to do that

```
let thisUserId = "uid_0"
func addThisUserIdToFriendsNode() {
    let usersRef = self.ref.child("users") //the general users node
    let thisUserRef = usersRef.child(self.thisUserId) //this users node
    let thisUserFriends = thisUserRef.child("friends") //this users list of friends

    //load in all of this users friends
    thisUserFriends.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        let allOfThisUsersFriends = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
        for user in allOfThisUsersFriends {
            let friendRef = usersRef.child(user.key) //the friend ref
            let friendsFriendRef = friendRef.child("friends") //a friend friends child node
            let nodeToAdd = friendsFriendRef.child(self.thisUserId) //add this uid
            nodeToAdd.setValue(true)
        }
    })
}
```

and the result

```
users
   uid_0
      name: "Larry"
      friends:
         uid_1: true
         uid_2: true
   uid_1
       name: "Moe"
       friends
          uid_0: true
   uid_2
       name: "Curly"
       friends
          uid_0: true
```

Comment: this is exactly the solution i was looking for, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question right, i think, you can try to use Cloud DataStore instead of RealtimeDB.
Difference description between this data bases you can find [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore).

Another way - use Firebase Functions.

Comment: Thanks for responding! So, should my for loop be working as it's constructed then?

Comment: I think, it should work. i guess.. =)
But if you choose Cloud DataStore, you can use higher quality queries than Firestore allows.

Comment: @pozzy I am not sure this is an appropriate answer. It doesn't appear you're asking how to query for data - you're asking how to read in a user node, access the child nodes (which are their friends uids) and then for each of those add this users uid to their friends nodes. That won't require any query as long as you know this users uid. The solution is pretty straightforward if that's your use case.

Comment: @Jay you are right, my apologize.
But, first one - if we talk about problem with value setting, so.. example that you add doesn't have some difference with Pozzy's code.
Pozzy set values similar as you.
Next - DataStore allow you to create batch updates. That's why i talked about this. 
And another one thing, maybe Pozzy has reached requests limit.

Comment: Agreed. There's a lot of extraneous code in the question and it's not clear why some of the code was included - like the *addCurrentUserToCloseFriendsLists*. I was trying to reduce the code to a smaller footprint to accomplish the task via an example. But yeah - it could a number of other issues as well.

Comment: I think, i know where is a problem. 
Best way - simply add friend id in "friends" array if user add someone to friends, and remove friend id if friendship gone.
If we try to add value for nonexistent key, of course we get an error and non-workable request. 
Please, take a look at this moment.

Comment: @Jay your solution worked! And now that I know what the steps to take, I know what parts of my code were extraneous